# Is it possible to pass a parameter that is DB.null and set a value in the database equal to that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlclient

I'm pulling data from a database (1 record) and putting each value in a textbox or dropdownlist.  Some of these values are DB.null.  If they are, I convert each of them to "" (blank).  However, once the user has modified the textboxes/dropdown list, they can "Save" the new results.  My problem is this:

If the user leaves something blank, I want to be able to maintain that the value is DB.null.  Is there a way to do this?

Also, is it possible that if there is a value in a textbox and the user decides to delete it, I can also convert it to DB.Null?  Here's what I tried to do to give you guys some idea:

```
productName != ""
    ? myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", productName)
    : myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Looks like you tried `DBNull.Value` already, did this fail?

Comment: One other thing you can do is simply not pass the parameter to the stored procedure - that is if no selection was made.  Something as simple as `if txtBox.Length > 0 //pass param else //dont pass param`

Comment: Is the empty string a valid value in your database? If so how will you differentiate between a deliberate empty string and a "null" empty string?

Comment: Chris - No, empty string is NOT valid.  That's why I want to be able to convert to DB.NULL.
AdamHouldsworth - Yes it did fail for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With SQL Server I believe you can interchangably use `null` or `DBNull.Value` to set a value to `NULL`.

I'd also change your code to this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@ProductName",
    // this requires a cast as ?: must return the same type
    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productName)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : (object)productName
);
```

Or using `null` and without an explicit cast:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@ProductName",
    ! String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productName) ? productName : null
);
```

Comment: You will need to cast DBNull.Value and productName to object for ?: operator to work (if not the operator will not be able to identify the resulting type).

Comment: @tpeczek Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't run this in VS. Editing now. And incidentally I believe this is why I had used `null` in the past as it doesn't require a cast.

Comment: @Yuck Will your second method work?  I thought null was different from DB.null?

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla `null` and `DBNull.Value` are definitely different types (i.e. `DBNull.Value != null == true`), but the SQL client will recognize either as the application wanting to set the value `NULL` in the database.

Comment: @Yuck Thanks!  May I ask then why you didn't simply use null in the first example?  This would have kept you from having to typecast to (object).

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla Some people prefer using `DBNull.Value` to `null` for consistency. When you're working with a `SqlDataReader` it will map `NULL` in the database to `DBNull.Value` and not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

It is valid to check for empty string and then use:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", DBNull.Value)
```

if it is, like:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductName)) {

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", DBNull.Value);

} else {

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", ProductName);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with .Net 2.0 or above, consider leveraging the [Nullable(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) structure. It makes it really easy to test for Null values and you can simply drop the .Value property of the object into your TextBox if they specified a value. These objects default to null, so when you go to update records in the database, if no value was specifed, you leave the variable alone and NULL will make it into your database.

I'll admit there are a little odd to work with at first (you have to remember to use the .Value property when binding to a TextBox) but after that initial hurdle the structure is quite handy if you're going to be dealing with a lot of database fields that can potentially have nullable values.

Answer (score 0):

Best not to tie data-centric types (like `DBNull`) with your `TextBox`. While it may make your code look cleaner on the data side there's no built-in way to automatically convert an empty string to and from `DBNull`.

A clean way on your DB side would be

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@ProductName",
    productName.IsNullOrEmpty() ? (object)(DBNull.Value) : productName
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter version:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@ProductName", 
    productName == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)productName
);
```