# adding to database: parameter not supplied but it's not required in SQL column

Tags: c#, sql

So, I can successfully add a new band to the database but sometimes I don't need all the parameters. In my database "Picture" and "Description" are allowed to have "null" value, so why does C# keeps giving me the error message that the parameter is not supplied?

```
public static void AddBand(Band band){
    try
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Band(Naam, Picture, Description, Facebook, Twitter) VALUES(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5)";
        DbParameter p1 = Database.AddParameter("@p1", band.Name);
        DbParameter p2 = Database.AddParameter("@p2", band.Picture);
        DbParameter p3 = Database.AddParameter("@p3", band.Description);
        DbParameter p4 = Database.AddParameter("@p4", band.Facebook);
        DbParameter p5 = Database.AddParameter("@p5", band.Twitter);

        Database.ModifyData(sql, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);

        MessageBox.Show("Band successfully added.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: C# `null` values differ from the ones used in SQL. 
Try using `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Are you sometimes not supplying the parameter even though it is in your query?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: There is quite a bit of context missing here. Namely, what is `Database`, what does `ModifyData` do exactly, and are you leveraging the `AddWithValue` method on the `IDbCommand`'s parameter collection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491337/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-parameter-that-is-db-null-and-set-a-value-in-the-databa

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query says a parameter is not supplied, but is added to the SqlCommand object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282143/sql-query-says-a-parameter-is-not-supplied-but-is-added-to-the-sqlcommand-objec)

Comment: @Chris Yes, sometimes I'm not supplying the parameter but it is in my parameter just in case I do supply it.

Comment: @KyleHale I don't see how I need to do this for every parameter that isn't required.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud ModifyData will just build a new command and update the database, not really important here. Database is the class where I make connection etc, ...

Comment: @user2759675 Then there is your problem. If you're specifying the parameter in your query, you must also supply the parameter when sending it to the server. As one answer below states, send it with DBNull.Value.

Comment: You should use **more intuitively obvious** names for your parameters than `@p1` through `@p5` .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ADO.NET, if a parameter has a value of `null`, it ***is not sent***. You need to replace the .NET `null` with `DBNull.Value` if you mean to represent a database `null`. Yes, it sucks.

```
DbParameter p1 = Database.AddParameter("@p1", (object)band.Name ?? DBNull.Value);
DbParameter p2 = Database.AddParameter("@p2", (object)band.Picture ?? DBNull.Value);
DbParameter p3 = Database.AddParameter("@p3", (object)band.Description ?? DBNull.Value);
DbParameter p4 = Database.AddParameter("@p4", (object)band.Facebook ?? DBNull.Value);
DbParameter p5 = Database.AddParameter("@p5", (object)band.Twitter ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Alternatively, use something like "dapper" to save you pain:

```
conn.Execute(@"INSERT INTO Band(Naam, Picture, Description, Facebook, Twitter)
    VALUES(@Name,@Picture,@Description,@Facebook,@Twitter)", band);
```

which will a: simplify your data-access code hugely, and b: get these obscure rules right automatically.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This helped and worked. Good explanation. Thanks to others aswell for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute sp with whole number of its parameters and pass DBNull.Value as value for those who intended to be null

Comment: You can use `NULL` within `INSERT INTO`. So this is a solution, but doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: @Pathfinder Thanks, any idea how I can do this? I don't see how I can solve this

Answer (score 0):

If parameter is null:

- Sent it as DBNull.Value
  or
- Do not send it at all, but define a default value for that parameter in stored procedure:

Here it is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <MyProcedure>
@p1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@p2 INT = NULL
...
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Always supply the database parameters with your query if the query specifies them. If it is nullable, check it and supply a DBNull.Value for that parameter.

```
public static void AddBand(Band band){
    try
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Band(Naam, Picture, Description, Facebook, Twitter) VALUES(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5)";
        DbParameter p1 = Database.AddParameter("@p1", band.Name);
        DbParameter p2 = Database.AddParameter("@p2", band.Picture 
            ?? DBNull.Value);
        DbParameter p3 = Database.AddParameter("@p3", band.Description 
            ?? DBNull.Value);
        DbParameter p4 = Database.AddParameter("@p4", band.Facebook);
        DbParameter p5 = Database.AddParameter("@p5", band.Twitter);

        Database.ModifyData(sql, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);

        MessageBox.Show("Band successfully added.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```